# Connect to RDS from VPS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am trying to transfer an existing mysql database that is located on my VPS to AWS RDS.

I have RDS set up and I am able to connect to the server just fine by connecting to one of my ec2 instances through ssh and using this command:

```
mysql -uuser -p -hxx.xx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

However, when I try to connect from my VPS (through ssh) I receive an ERROR 2003, which I believe is permission denied.

It doesn't seem to matter how I set my security group. I set the inbound to allow port 3306 from my server ip and that did not work, I even tried allowing all traffic on all ports from anywhere on my inbound rules and I still am unable to connect. The outbound has always been completely open.

If anyone can see anything that I am missing I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using RDS, or mysql installed on an EC2 machine? Those are 2 different things, and you seem to have them mixed up. You can allow "all traffic on all ports" on an EC2 machine, but not RDS (either another security group, or a CIDR/IP).

Comment: I am using rds. There is no database on the EC2 but the application on the EC2 instance will be using the RDS for the database. I have an existing database that I want to transfer from my VPS to RDS. Before I allowed all traffic on all ports in the security group (the security group is used for the RDS not EC2) I had tried only allowing my CIDR/IP. This was unsuccessful.

Comment: As per the answer below, make sure you 1) are using the host string, user and database provided when you created the instance 2) added the EC2 security group to the RDS security group 3) perhaps dump the DB from your VPS to the EC2 machine and import it into RDS from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your RDS instance is set to **public** if you want to access it externally. If in fact it's not publicly accessible then you'll need to recreate your instance and import your data, or take a snapshot and rebuild your RDS instance from the snapshot.

You only have ONE chance to modify it and that is at instance creation.

[image]

If you do this then make sure you security group only allows from a specific IP address or if you're using MySQL workbench rather use a SSH tunnel using SSH keys via an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Is `user` a user you created manually in your RDS, or is it the admin user that was created when you created the instance? If the former, then make sure you have granted access to that user from your remote VPS.

Also, from your VPS, make sure you can open a TCP connection to the database. Try:

`$ nc -v -z xx.xx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com 3306`

If the connection succeeds here but you still can't connect with the mysql CLI, you have a problem with the username/password/database connection info.

Comment: Install netcat, or use telnet instead if you have that.